# Loop over Json using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my Json Data received from Ajax response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "errorCode": "0001",
        "errorText": "SUCCESS"
    },
    "responselist": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "event": [
                {
                    "startDate": null,
                    "eventId": 1234,
                    "eventName": "Interview",
                    "modifiedUser": "User",
                    "eventTypeCode": "1",
                    "eventVenue": null,
                    "eventSpecialInst": "isnsdf",
                    "eventStatusCode": "OP",
                    "eventLangCode": "Eng",
                    "eventDesc": "sdfsadfsd",
                    "fromEmailId": "Abcd@apple.com",
                    "rsvpDeadline": 5,
                    "canceledInd": "yes",
                    "canceldEmailText": "sdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdf",
                    "daysToWaitlistLastCall": 5,
                    "daysToReminderAdmin": 6,
                    "daysToReminderEvent": 3,
                    "daysToReminderInvitation": 2,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "venueAddrLine1": null,
                    "venueAddrLine2": null,
                    "venueAddrLine3": null,
                    "cityCode": null,
                    "stateCode": null,
                    "appId": null,
                    "modifiedDate": "2010-12-16",
                    "countryCode": null,
                    "zipCode": null,
                    "user_id": null,
                    "updateFlag": "R"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": null,
                    "eventId": 4321,
                    "eventName": "Seasonal Hiring",
                    "modifiedUser": "User",
                    "eventTypeCode": "1",
                    "eventVenue": null,
                    "eventSpecialInst": "isnsdf",
                    "eventStatusCode": "OP",
                    "eventLangCode": "Eng",
                    "eventDesc": "sdfsadfsd",
                    "fromEmailId": "Abcd@apple.com",
                    "rsvpDeadline": 5,
                    "canceledInd": "yes",
                    "canceldEmailText": "sdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdf",
                    "daysToWaitlistLastCall": 5,
                    "daysToReminderAdmin": 6,
                    "daysToReminderEvent": 3,
                    "daysToReminderInvitation": 2,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "venueAddrLine1": "KFC",
                    "venueAddrLine2": "The Forum",
                    "venueAddrLine3": "Koramangala",
                    "cityCode": "Bangalore",
                    "stateCode": "Karnataka",
                    "appId": null,
                    "modifiedDate": "2010-12-16",
                    "countryCode": "India",
                    "zipCode": "560040",
                    "user_id": null,
                    "updateFlag": "R"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using below code to extract information inside **event** object. But I am not able to do it. Need guidance.

```
$.ajax({ url:"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/service/showInvitedEvents/21",

         dataType:"json", 
         success: function(jsonData) 
         {
           alert("Inside response success");

           $.each(jsonData.responselist.event,function(i,item)
          $.each(Employees,function(i,item)
           {
             alert('Iteration is' + i);
            var teventName = item.eventName;

            var teventVenue = item.eventVenue;
            var tstartDate = item.startDate;
            var tendDate = item.endDate;
            var tstarend = tstartDate +" - "+ tendDate ;            

            $("#eventTable tbody").append("<tr><td><a id="+teventName+i+" href=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/service/session/1234>"+teventName+"</a></td><td>"+teventVenue+"</td><td>"+tstarend+"</td></tr>");

           });
```

Comment: You don't loop over JSON. You decode the JSON, then loop over the resultant JavaScript objects.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but rather a tip: jQuery-append is pretty resource intensive. Better concatenate it with a variable (via +) and then use one jQuery-append when the string is complete.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can't loop over jsonData.responselist.event. jsonData.responselist is an array so either need to make a double loop or if you always know there is one and only one item in responslist you could loop over jsonData.responselist[0].event

For the rest of it I'm not sure why you have this row:

```
$.each(Employees,function(i,item)
```

Looks like a misstake to as it isn't valid there(the syntax is wrong and it hides both i and item from the real each).

Comment: Yes..$.each(Employees,function(i,item) was a typo errro my mistake. Followed your suggestion and I worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the following line in your code:?

```
$.each(Employees,function(i,item)
```

Try removing it and see what happens.